# 301 redirecting a blog's RSS feed URL?

Tags: wordpress, rss, nginx, feeds, ghost-blog

I moved my personal blog from Wordpress to Ghost this weekend, which changes the RSS feed URL from `/feed/` to `/rss/`.

By default Ghost returns a 301 redirect for `/feed/`, which I've verified by checking the response header and looking at the logs:

[image: server logs]

In Feedly though, new posts aren't being picked up (at least after 24 hours. I'm not sure if they might have a waiting period before updating the URL). What's the correct thing to do in this situation? Do I need to keep `/feed/` alive instead of returning a 301? If so, is there a rewrite rule that would let me do this in nginx instead of having to modify the Ghost source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was right about Feedly waiting to pick up the new URL. It took over a full day but new posts are finally showing up. I guess just letting Ghost do a 301 is the proper solution, after all.